# Is it ok to assume that the Java Concurrent Mark Sweep Garbage Collector is equally good on Linux and Mac as well as Windows?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, operating-system, jvm, concurrent-mark-sweep

I have been looking for information on the web regarding use of the Java Concurrent Mark Sweep GC for Linux and Mac or for different versions of Java.  I'm specifically interested in the latest versions of Oracle Java 1.6 and 1.7.

I'll assume that it runs because I haven't found anything to the contrary, but are there any noticeable differences of the performance as compared to Windows, including on OpenJDK?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the JVM implementation. **You did not specify** the JVM **vendor/distribution** you are interested in. I am sure there are VMs out there where you can see a performance difference depending on the OS.

But, in general **as long as only the GC algorithm** is concerned, **there will be no difference** on any platform because the code implementing the GC algorithm is the same. The GC algorithm is accessing an API for low level system routines that implement the allocation/deallocation of the memory. The implementation of such API depends on OS.

Comment: Edited my answer to add the info on vendor/distribution.  What I'd like to find is some insight into the effect of these OS differences on the GC and whether it's significant enough to decide for/against using it for multiplatform software.